# (Srednicki) How to obtain the normalization condition for Dirac field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, spinors, s-matrix-theory, normalization

I'm reading through srednicki's qft and I met a problem. In its section 41, after he make an assumption that the creation operators of free field
theory would work comparably in the interacting theory , he derived the LSZ formula for the Dirac field, and those assumptions led to some normalization conditions for the Dirac field. One of those conditions is (41.24),(41.25):$$
\begin{aligned}
&\langle p, s,-|\Psi(x)| 0\rangle=v_{s}(p) e^{-i p x} \\
&\langle p, s,+|\bar{\Psi}(x)| 0\rangle=\bar{u}_{s}(p) e^{-i p x}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Psi$is the Dirac field, $|p,s,+\rangle$ is a state for electron with spin s and momentum p and $|p,s,-\rangle$ stands for an antielectron. He says that it can be derived from the Lorentz invariance of the vacuum state, up to an fixing constant.

My first question is, how to derive those two formula up to a constant? Fortunately I find srednicki's solution to this in his problem solution for his problem 41.1 in which he used the lorentz transformation property of the one particle state $\langle p, s, q| U(\Lambda)=\sum_{s^{\prime}} R_{s s^{\prime}}(\Lambda, \mathbf{p})\left\langle\Lambda^{-1} p, s^{\prime}, q\right|$ to verify the formula, we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle p, s, q|\Psi(x)| 0\rangle &=\left\langle p, s, q\left|U(\Lambda) U(\Lambda)^{-1} \Psi(x) U(\Lambda) U(\Lambda)^{-1}\right| 0\right\rangle \\
&=\sum_{s^{\prime}} R_{s s^{\prime}}(\Lambda, \mathbf{p}) D(\Lambda)\left\langle\Lambda^{-1} p, s^{\prime}, q\left|\Psi\left(\Lambda^{-1} x\right)\right| 0\right\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$where $R_{s s^{\prime}}(\Lambda, \mathbf{p})=-\frac{1}{2 m} \bar{v}_{s^{\prime}}\left(\Lambda^{-1} \mathbf{p}\right) \overline{D(\Lambda)} v_{s}(\mathbf{p})$.Then we can plug in the normalization formula and check that the both sides are equal, after cancel the exponential, LHS=$v_s(p)$, and$$
\begin{aligned}
RHS &{=}-\frac{1}{2 m} \sum_{s^{\prime}} D(\Lambda) v_{s^{\prime}}\left(\Lambda^{-1} \mathbf{p}\right) \bar{v}_{s^{\prime}}\left(\Lambda^{-1} \mathbf{p}\right) \overline{D(\Lambda)} v_{s}(\mathbf{p}) \\
& {=}-\frac{1}{2 m} D(\Lambda)\left(-\Lambda^{-1} \not p-m\right) \overline{D(\Lambda)} v_{s}(\mathbf{p}) \\
& {=}-\frac{1}{2 m}(-\not p-m) v_{s}(\mathbf{p}) \\
& {=}-\frac{1}{2 m}(-m-m) v_{s}(\mathbf{p}) \\
& {=} v_{s}(\mathbf{p})
\end{aligned}
$$ so there only remains a small problem: how to derive the third identity above?

And my second question is, how to show that the two formulas are actually not independent and can be related by charge conjugation?

Comment: What goes wrong when you repeat the calculation he does for scalars?